# Why has seahorse-plugins been removed?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, encryption, seahorse

I've been encrypting and decrypting files and folder using nautilus and the seahorse-plugins package for the past few Ubuntu releases. It appears that seahorse-plugins is no longer available in oneiric's repos: see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=seahorse-plugins), and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/seahorse-plugins).

Has it been replaced by another tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking a bit further there is this [bug report #796752](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/seahorse-plugins/+bug/796752/) on Launchpad which seems to lay the blame on the transition to Gnome 3. Looks like it might be available in Precise.

Comment: is it going to be backported to oneiric?